# How to dynamically change meta property type in PHP

Tags: php, metadata, facebook-opengraph

I'm working on a WordPress site and am trying to dynamically define a meta property by detecting the page URL.

If on website homepage then echo "website"
Else echo "article"

```
<meta property="og:type" content="
    <?php
    $host = parse_url($domain, PHP_URL_HOST);
    if($host == 'http://www.domain.com') {
    echo $this->__('website')
    }
    else
    {
    echo $this->__('article')
    }
    ?> " />
```

This doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: You expect copypaste PHP code or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to paste what I had come up with.

Comment: Please go read the documentation with wordpress as without referring to that - you're just reinventing the wheel and potentially opening security holes / creating highly unmaintainable code.

Comment: I'm not a PHP developer so just looking for some help with what I have or a copy/paste of what I should use.  I spent over an hour Googling around to try and find a solution but everything I tried didn't work.  Sorry for the noobness.

Comment: So go and read the documentation. If you're not comfortable with PHP **why are you messing with the code!?**. You could cause a serious problem by writing bad code. I'm all for learning so please don't let me put you off but the documentation is exceptionally clear at wordpress. Plus the support forums there are more suited for your question. Have a try there?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do any research into this? I suspect not. You can get condition code example here - https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
  // Default homepage
} elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
  // static homepage
} elseif ( is_home() ) {
  // blog page
} else {
  //everyting else
}
```